# What is the locahost for oracle 11g xe?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, hibernate, web-applications

I'm doing a hibernate project for my final semester. I don't know what to enter here in my project for the hibernate configuration file `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost: :XE`.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` refers to your local machine. In the case you describe with Oracle, you need to specify the Oracle instance on your local machine. By default Oracle runs on port `1521` e.g. `localhost:1521`.

To solve your problem, you should update your jdbc connection string to include the port.

Thus, your connection string should look something like the following:

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) is the Oracle JDBC API doc. It explains how to construct the connection url.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the port number.
You have to see what port your database is using

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1525:XE
```

It is normally 1525